# How to use requests (Python) to log in a website with no obvious csrf token

Tags: python, python-requests, csrf

In advance I apologize for my poor technical vocabulary, I'm pretty new to this...

I would like to write a python script (Python 3.6) that enables me to enter in a website page that requires a login (the final aim being to download some xls files on this page but this is a problem for another time).

I looked into a certain number of tutorials and stack overflow questions and it does not seems that complicated. Problem is, in the html of the login URL, there is no attribute such as 'csrf token' or equivalent, so I can not log in!

When inspecting the login page in more details, here are the attributes that are in the Network bookmark > login > Headers > Form Data when I inspect it during login (hope it is understandable): _VIEWSTATE, _VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, _EVENTVALIDATION, LocaleList, UserLoginBox, UserPasswordBox, LoginButton, NewLocale

I tried the following code (inspired from Kazuar's scraping tuto on github):

```
import requests
session_requests = requests.session()

# Get login csrf token
result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)

# authenticity_tok = 
# list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]

# Create payload
payload = {
    "UserLoginBox": USERNAME, 
    "UserPasswordBox": PASSWORD, 
   # "authenticity_token": authenticity_tok
}

# Perform login
result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = 
dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

# Scrape url
result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
```

I commented everything that relies on the token since there are no token. I also tried with cookies['csrftoken'] which I also found on tutorials or stack overflow questions but it did not gave any better result: when printing result.text, it always print the login page html, not the target page html (URL).

Moreover, in the head of the login html page, there is a javascript src = 
https://bam.nr-data.net/1/4bff676375?a=2169850&v=1071.385e752&to=ZgQHNRNRXUBVVUxZXV9OJDIxH19cU19WHlNCER0%3D&rst=3041&ref=TARGET_URL/(S(yo4yj1w4uqy5qsbkkx2au4xy))/Login.aspx&ap=12&be=1440&fe=2981&dc=2009&tt=E5CA72AB96D7B87&perf=%7B"timing":%7B"of":1522250168464,"n":0,"u":943,"ue":944,"f":14,"dn":29,"dne":307,"c":307,"s":453,"ce":754,"rq":754,"rp":918,"rpe":1070,"dl":979,"di":2009,"ds":2009,"de":2039,"dc":2978,"l":2978,"le":3002%7D,"navigation":%7B%7D%7D&jsonp=NREUM.setToken

Could it be something useful to log in? What should I do?

I would be really thankful if anyone had an idea and could help me. I do not indicate the URLs because I hope it can be done without it (may be private company stuff)...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the existence of __VIEWSTATE it suggests that this is an ASP.NET site using webforms....which will cause you a considerable amount of pain when trying to POST requests directly to it.

I would suggest using Selenium (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to create a headless browser & interact with the page as a "normal" user.

Whilst it is extra work, you will find it easier than trying to work with ASP.NET webforms

Comment: Thank you a lot for this quick response, @justcompile! I'll try this out then!